# What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?

Tags: functions, undocumented

There have already been some questions about some undocumented functionality in *Mathematica*. Such as (*please add to these lists!*)

- [How can one find undocumented options or option values in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7087149/421225)
- [What do these undocumented Style options in Mathematica do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6894237/421225)
- [Undocumented command-line options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771946/421225)

Also, other questions and answers that contained undocumented functions

- [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686710/421225) (also in [Exposing Symbols to $ContextPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7912984/421225))
- `` Internal`Bag `` (in [Implementing a Quadtree in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762/421225)) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452146/421225))
- `RuleCondition` (in [Replace inside Held expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7679152/211232))

Along with the "Undocumented (or scarcely documented) Features" segment of the [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4198961/421225) question.

[Szabolcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695132/szabolcs) also maintains a list of [Mathematica tricks](http://web.ift.uib.no/%7Eszhorvat/mmatricks.php) which contains a list of "undocumented stuff", which can now be found archived [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140823044625/http://web.ift.uib.no/%7Eszhorvat/mmatricks.php).

---

**So, what undocumented functions do you know and how do you use them?**
(Added useful information is maybe how you discovered the functions and any version dependence.)

Comment: I guess I have to state the obvious here and that is using undocumented functions/options can break with major or even minor mathematica upgrades. My advice is to stay away unless you like to experiment and have a lot of time on your hands.

Comment: J.M. mentioned ``Internal`FromPiecewise`` in [(27254)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27254/121) if anyone feels like writing an answer about it.

Comment: @Kuba, Is it possible to edit this question to the style of `community wiki`?

Comment: I don't know. No need for that on the other hand, this is a good question.

Comment: @Kuba, Thanks, I use *Mathematica* in my study everyday  and I like *Mathematica* and StackSxchange which give me knowledge and happy.:)

Comment: Indeed, this is a nice question -looking forward to the answers

Comment: Extremely shocked to see `Internal\`CompareNumeric` missing, but then I realised that your image is not the full list. Good question.

Comment: @OleksandrR., Thanks, Image is just a part of the full list:)

Comment: I wonder what the purpose of Internal`Square[] is?

Comment: I would add ``Internal`AbsSquare``. So much time lost computing the square root in `Abs` or `Norm` just to undo it a moment later in quantum mechanical calculations.

Comment: An archived version of the dead link: http://web.archive.org/web/20140823044625/http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php

Comment: [(155433)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155433/121)

Answer (score 90):

- **`LongestCommonSequencePositions` and `LongestCommonSubsequencePositions`**  Their use is analogous to `LongestCommon(Sub)sequence` but they return the position of the first match instead.

  **Update:** These are documented since 10.2.
- **`ClipboardNotebook[]`** can be used to access the clipboard.  `NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[]` will give a `Notebook` expression with the current contents of the clipboard.  I use this for pre-processing data before it is pasted (e.g. in the [table paste palette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433867/695132)).  I am not sure if this can be used for copying at all---I use the Front End's Copy function directly for that (through `FrontEndTokenExecute`)

  **Update:** Since version 8 we have [some documented clipboard functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ClipboardOperations.html).
- **`PolynomialForm[]`** allows changing the order in which polynomial terms are printed by setting the option `TraditionalOrder -> True`

  ```
  In[1]:= PolynomialForm[1+x+x^2, TraditionalOrder->True]
  Out[1]= x^2+x+1
  ```
- **POST request:** In version 8 `Import` has [experimental support for the POST HTTP request method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345690/695132).  Example usage for [uploading an image to imgur](https://api.imgur.com/#anonapi):

  ```
  Import["http://api.imgur.com/2/upload", "XML", 
         "RequestMethod" -> "POST", 
         "RequestParameters" -> {"key" -> apikey, "image" -> image}]
  ```

  (Of course you'll need to insert your API key and a properly encoded image, as shown in the answer I linked to above.)
- **`` Internal`Deflatten[] ``** will reconstruct higher dimensional tensor from a flat list.  Example:

  ```
  In[1]:= arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
  Out[1]= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

  In[2]:= flatArr = Flatten[arr]
  Out[2]= {1, 2, 3, 4}

  In[3]:= Internal`Deflatten[flatArr, Dimensions[arr]]
  Out[3]= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
  ```

  *Warning:* If the dimensions passed to it don't match the length of the flat array, this will crash the kernel!

  **Update:** Version 9.0 introduced the documented equivalent [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html).

---

- **Image capture start/stop**  `` IMAQ`StartCamera[] `` and `` IMAQ`StopCamera[] `` start and stop the webcam.

---

- **Undocumented interesting contexts** to dig through: `` Internal`, Experimental`, Language` ``, `` NotebookTools` `` (similar to what the `AuthorTools` package offers), `` IMAQ` `` (IMage AQcuisition)

  There are lots of functions in these contexts, generally undocumented, but sometimes with self-explanatory names (e.g. `` Internal`RealValuedNumericQ `` seems obvious).  Note that these functions might change in later versions.  Some of the ones listed by `` ?Internal`* `` are even from old versions and no longer work in M- 8.

  Some functions from `` Language` `` are described [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/0hw5IkrdsTU/v2404uYo9GsJ).

---

- **[`SystemOptions[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SystemOptions.html)**  The functions to set and read these options are not undocumented, but the options themselves unfortunately are.

  - **`` Experimental`SystemOptionsEditor[] ``**  In version 8 this gives a GUI for viewing/setting system options.
  - **`"TableCompileLength"`** (and other similar options from the `"CompileOptions"`) section set the length of a `Table` above which it attempts to compile its argument.

    Example: `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength"]` will show that the default value is 250.
  - **`"SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}`**

    Setting this option to 1 will cause repeated entries to be summed up when creating a sparse array.  [See an example use and explanation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203344/695132)

    ```
    In[1]:= Normal@SparseArray[{2 -> 1, 4 -> 1}]
    Out[1]= {0, 1, 0, 1}

    In[2]:= Normal@SparseArray[{2 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 1}]
    Out[2]= {0, 1, 0, 1}

    In[3]:= SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}]

    In[4]:= Normal@SparseArray[{2 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 1}]
    Out[4]= {0, 2, 0, 1}
    ```

---

[This MathGroup thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/s9r9qoVbgXY/discussion) has some interesting information too.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out what you mean by "The functions to set and read these options are not undocumented, but the options themselves unfortunately are."  There's likely a typo which I can't figure out; would you kindly fix?  Thanks.

Comment: @QuantumDot "are not undocumented" means "are documented". So, it means we know how to set options, but unfortunately do not know what those options mean.

Answer (score 59):

The following simulates *Mathematica*'s behaviour after using it for more than 24 hrs.

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`UndocumentedCrashFrontEndPacket[]]
```

Works as advertised! :D

Comment: That make my day! :D

Comment: OMG! I thought you were kidding...

Comment: I wonder how it was discovered, can't find it in ````Names["*`*"]````

Comment: @navigaid see this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13451/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-frontend-packet-types

Comment: Oh wow ok I thought I was just crazy (I am but still)

Answer (score 57):

One undocumented function I find useful is `Precedence`:

For example:

```matlab
{#, Precedence@#} & /@ {Plus, Minus, Times, Power, Apply, Map, Factor,
    Prefix, Postfix, Infix} // TableForm
```

giving:

```matlab
Plus    310.
Minus   480.
Times   400.
Power   590.
Apply   620.
Map     620.
Factor  670.
Prefix  640.
Postfix 70.
Infix   630.
```

Precedence is described in the lecture *[A New Mathematica Programming Style](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7002/)* by Kris Carlson.

**Edit**

One from about a year ago, which was then considered 'under development', is `TableView`.
I wonder what has happened to it?

For example:

```matlab
Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 3}] // TableView
```

giving:

[image: Example of a TableView]

For the recent version 10.3,`TableView` cannot work normaly.

[image: Example of TableView not working in version 10.3]

Comment: I was thinking of adding `Precedence` here. Luckily I noticed your answer. Appropriately enough, I learned of this from a comment you made to a question on stackoverflow. +1

Comment: At a Wolfram Training Course in April '15  we were advised that TableView was being deprecated and not to use it as it caused frequent Kernel crashes.  Its been deleted from the help, although curiously still gives a hit for ListPicker.

Comment: As per a talk at WTC '18 I believe TableView might be coming back in 12.x.

Answer (score 56):

---

### Sequential [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html)

From [Daniel Lichtblau's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109298/is-there-any-way-to-implement-a-sequential-with-in-mathematica#comment296006_109298) there is a new undocumented syntax for [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) introduced sometime after version 10.1 that allows:

```
With[{a = 0}, {a = a + 1}, {a = a + 1}, a]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

---

### Delayed `With`, `Block`, and `Module`

These scoping constructs support the use of `:=` in definitions which allows one to handle unevaluated expressions.

```
With[{x := 2 + 2}, Trace[x]]
Block[{x := 2 + 2}, Trace[x]]
Module[{x := 2 + 2}, Trace[x]]
```

> ```
> {2 + 2, 4}
>
> {x, 2 + 2, 4}
>
> {x$6064, 2 + 2, 4}
> ```

#### Examples:

- I find this most useful in `With` since it inserts definitions into held expressions.
  I commonly use this for in-place modification of [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html):

  ```
   a[1] = Pi;
   a[2] = E;

   With[{dv := DownValues[a]},  dv = dv /. {1 -> 3};]

    a[3]   (*  out=  π  *)
  ```
- [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) finds it very useful for writing readable controllers definitions.

  E.g.

  ```
  asso = <|"nested" -> <|"key" -> <|
      "spec" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" ->  0|>
  |>|>|>;

  With[{
    a := asso["nested", "key", "spec", "a"],
    b := asso["nested", "key", "spec", "b"]
    },
   DynamicModule[{},
     Column@{
      Slider@Dynamic[a],
      Slider[Dynamic[b, {Automatic, (a = b^2) &}]],
      Dynamic@asso
      }
   ]

  ]
  ```

The earliest Stack Exchange usage of this that I can find is [a post by Szabolcs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8742627/618728).

I implemented a similar syntax in [my `listWith` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30646/121) which is itself an extension of `With`.

Comment: Is just the example unfortunately chosen? It seems to me that it works the same without `With`. `DownValues[a] = DownValues[a] /. {1 -> 3}; a[3]`

Comment: @Kuba I think I usually make `Dynamic` part of the definition in that case?  Does that fail in your typical application?  *edit:* Actually I remember that I use both, e.g. [(88458)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88458/121).  Would you care to edit this answer to include your example?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the example!

Comment: As an added variant, I often need to create random option values, and delayed `With` is perfect for this, e.g. `AxesLabel -> With[{x := RandomChoice[{None, Automatic, "North"}]}, RandomChoice[{x, {x, x}}]]`.

Comment: @rcollyer Now I am curious; why would you need random option values?

Comment: Testing. It's combinatorically impossible to cover all combinations, and you hope they're independent, we all know that isn't strictly true. So, for some tests, I'll generate random sets of options and see what blows up. Often it is the only way to get coverage.

Answer (score 51):

### Update

Since version 11.2, this function is now buried in a deeper context: `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[] ``.

---

I quite like `SequenceLimit[]` myself; it is a function that numerically estimates the limit of a sequence by applying the Shanks transformation (as embodied in [Wynn's $\varepsilon$ algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1956-0084056-6)). The method is a particularly nice generalization of the probably more well-known [Aitken $\delta^2$ transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitken%27s_delta-squared_process) for accelerating the convergence of a sequence. Another way of looking at it is that if one applies the Shanks transformation to a sequence whose terms correspond to partial sums of a power series, the transformation gives the results corresponding to the diagonal [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) formed from the partial sums.

Enough preamble, and let's see an example. Consider the sequence of iterates to the [cosine's fixed point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html):

```
seq = NestList[Cos, N[1, 30], 20];
```

and let's generate the number for comparison purposes:

```
dottie = x /. FindRoot[x == Cos[x], {x, 3/4}, WorkingPrecision -> 40]
0.7390851332151606416553120876738734040134
```

Compare:

```
Last[seq]
0.739184399771493638624201453905348

% - dottie
0.000099266556332996968889366231475
```

with

```
SequenceLimit[seq]
0.7390851332151606416553149654

% - dottie
2.87775364950904`5.313591998048321*^-24
```

It can be seen here that applying the Shanks transformation to the sequence of iterates gave a result which had more good digits than any of the iterates themselves. This is the power of the function `SequenceLimit[]`.

As with any powerful tool, however, some care is needed in its use. Consider for instance this example:

```
seq = N[Accumulate[((-1)^Range[0, 30]) Range[0,30]!], 30];
```

We have generated here a rather violently divergent sequence of partial sums $\sum\limits_k (-1)^k k!$. One would rightly be wary of trying to derive results from a sequence like this, but `SequenceLimit[]` manages to do something, even if it does spit out a warning:

```
SequenceLimit[seq]
   SequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined,
   and the result may be incorrect. >>
0.596347362

% - (-E ExpIntegralEi[-1])
0.*10^-10
```

and in fact the result can be justified through analytic continuation. However, that the algorithm can give unexpected results for divergent sequences is something to be mindful and careful of.

Comment: Interesting, it has a usage message, but is not in the documentation - it's also in the ``System` `` context, which is rare for undocumented functions. Do you think it forms the backend for `NSum[..., Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]`?

Comment: Yes, it's the method behind the `"WynnEpsilon"` options of `NSum[]`/`NProduct[]`.

Comment: This answer of mine http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95126/limit-of-partial-sums-involving-inverse-squares/95166#95166 has implementations of the Shanks transformation and Richardson extrapolation. I really wanted to include Richardson extrapolation in NSum, but got involved in NIntegrate ... By the way, the original author of NSum (Jerry Keiper) implemented his own modifications of the Wynn Epsilon algorithm.

Comment: @Anton, it does seem unfortunate that Keiper did not mention his modifications, as you say, of the Wynn algorithm. In any event: I note that your implementation of Shanks does not use the "rhombus rule", and your implementation of Richardson extrapolation does not exploit the recurrence's "triangular" nature. You might consider looking at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/36066)...

Comment: It is worth mentioning that despite its `N` prefix the function works on symbolic sequences as well, e.g. ```NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}]```.

Comment: @Vladimir, I suppose that would correspond to symbolically applying the Shanks transformation on the list of expressions given to it.

Comment: I gave an improved version of ``NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit``, in both Mathematica and C++ versions, along with symbolic and numeric examples here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178537/14489

Comment: This function is still being used, e.g. try NSum[(-1)^n/(Sqrt[n] + (-1)^n), {n, 3, Infinity}] this will print a warning from inside NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit (the series diverges, BTW), see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259342/82985

Answer (score 50):

Thinking about a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8455631/421225) made me wonder exactly which functions in *Mathematica* use [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html). You can find the list of `` System` `` functions that use that `Option` by running

```
Reap[Do[Quiet[If[Options[Symbol[i], Assumptions]=!={}, Sow[i], Options::optnf]], 
  {i, DeleteCases[Names["System`*"], _?(StringMatchQ[#, "$"~~__] &)]}]][[2, 1]]
```

which (can be more elegantly written using [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6368770/421225) and) returns
(in version 8)

```
{"ContinuedFractionK", "Convolve", "DifferenceDelta", "DifferenceRootReduce", "DifferentialRootReduce", "DirichletTransform", "DiscreteConvolve", "DiscreteRatio", "DiscreteShift", "Expectation", "ExpectedValue", "ExponentialGeneratingFunction", "FinancialBond", "FourierCoefficient", "FourierCosCoefficient", "FourierCosSeries", "FourierCosTransform", "FourierSequenceTransform", "FourierSeries", "FourierSinCoefficient", "FourierSinSeries", "FourierSinTransform", "FourierTransform", "FourierTrigSeries", "FullSimplify", "FunctionExpand", "GeneratingFunction", "Integrate", "InverseFourierCosTransform", "InverseFourierSequenceTransform", "InverseFourierSinTransform", "InverseFourierTransform", "InverseZTransform", "LaplaceTransform", "Limit", "PiecewiseExpand", "PossibleZeroQ", "PowerExpand", "Probability", "ProbabilityDistribution", "Product", "Refine", "Residue", "Series", "SeriesCoefficient", "Simplify", "Sum", "SumConvergence", "TimeValue", "ToRadicals", "TransformedDistribution", "ZTransform"}
```

You can similarly look for functions that take assumptions that are not in the `` System` `` context and the main ones you find are in `` Names["Developer`*Simplify*"] `` which are (adding "Developer`" to the context path)

```
{"BesselSimplify", "FibonacciSimplify", "GammaSimplify", 
 "HolonomicSimplify", "PolyGammaSimplify", "PolyLogSimplify", 
 "PseudoFunctionsSimplify", "ZetaSimplify"}
```

These are all specialized simplification routines that are not called by `Simplify` but are called by `FullSimplify`. However, sometimes `FullSimplify` can take too long on large expressions and I can imagine calling these specialized routines would be useful. Here's a simple usage example

```
In[49]:= FunctionsWolfram["10.08.17.0012.01"] /. Equal -> Subtract // Simplify
         % // Developer`PolyLogSimplify

Out[49]= -Pi^2/6 + Log[1 - z] Log[z] + PolyLog[2, 1 - z] + PolyLog[2, z]

Out[50]= 0
```

(The `FunctionsWolfram` code is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6182889/421225))

---

Another interesting assumption related context I noticed was `` Assumptions` ``.
Once again, appending `` "Assumptions`" `` to the `$ContextPath`,
`` Names["Assumptions`*"] `` returns the functions

```
{"AAlgebraicQ", "AAssumedIneqQ", "AAssumedQ", "ABooleanQ", 
"AComplexQ", "AEvaluate", "AEvenQ", "AImpossibleIneqQ", "AInfSup", 
"AIntegerQ", "AllAssumptions", "AMathIneqs", "AMod", "ANegative", 
"ANonNegative", "ANonPositive", "AOddQ", "APositive", "APrimeQ", 
"ARationalQ", "ARealIfDefinedQ", "ARealQ", "ASign", "AssumedFalse", 
"AUnequalQ", "AWeakSign", "ImpliesQ"}
```

These contain assumption aware versions of some standard system functions, e.g.

```
In[22]:= Assuming[Element[x, Integers], {IntegerQ[x], AIntegerQ[x]}]
         Assuming[x > 0, {Positive[x], APositive[x]}]

Out[22]= {False, True}

Out[23]= {Positive[x], True}
```

Answer (score 46):

## System`

The default value for the overhang parameter `k` (3rd argument) in `ListCorrelate` is `None`.

## Internal` Predicates

`` Internal`LinearQ[expr, var] `` yields `True` if expr is a polynomial of exactly order one in `var`, and yields `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`RationalFunctionQ[expr,var] `` returns `True` if `expr` is a rational function of the symbol `var`, and returns `False` otherwise.  `` Internal`RationalFunctionQ[expr,{var1, var2,...}] `` checks that `expr` is rational in each of the `var_i`. ([ref](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RationalFunctionQ))

`` Internal`RealValuedNumberQ[expr] `` yields `True` if expr is a real-valued number, and `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`RealValuedNumericQ[expr] `` yields `True` if expr is a real-valued numeric quantity, and `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`DependsOnQ[expr, form] `` yields `True` if a subexpression in expr matches form (excluding heads) and mathematically depends on form, and yields `False` otherwise.  Takes a third argument (`True`/`False`, but behavior seems to be independent of choice) but seems to include heads also ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64245/2048))

`` Internal`EPolyQ[expr,var] `` yields `True` if expr is a polynomial in `var` and is in expanded form with respect to `var`.  *(New in 11.2)*

`` Internal`ExceptionFreeQ[expr] `` yields `True` if expr evaluates to something that contains `Infinity`, `DirectedInfinity`, or `Indeterminate`, and yields `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`FundamentalDiscriminantQ[expr] `` yields `True` if expr is a [fundamental discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_discriminant) `Integer` with the exception of 1, and `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`GregorianLeapYearQ[expr] `` yields `True` if the expr is an integer that corresponds to a leap year of the Gregorian Calendar, and `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ[expr, form] `` yields `True` if a subexpression in expr *explicitly* matches form, ignoring any `Attributes` of heads that might ordinarily influence the pattern matcher, and yields `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`LiterallyAbsentQ[expr, form] `` yields `True` if no subexpression in expr matches form, and yields `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`TestIntegerQ[number, form] `` yields {number, `True`} if number is an `Integer`, and {number, `False`} otherwise.

`` Internal`WouldBeNumericQ[expr, {var_1, var_2, ...}] `` yields `True` if expr would become a numeric quantity if the var_i were all numeric quantities, and `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`PatternFreeQ[expr] `` yields `True` if expr does not contain any of {`Alternatives`, `Blank`, `BlankNullSequence`, `BlankSequence`, `Except`, `Longest`, `Optional`, `OptionsPattern`, `OrderlessPatternSequence`, `PatternSequence`, `Repeated`, `RepeatedNull`, `Shortest`}, and `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`PatternPresentQ[expr] `` yields `True` if expr contains any of {`Alternatives`, `Blank`, `BlankNullSequence`, `BlankSequence`, `Except`, `Longest`, `Optional`, `OptionsPattern`, `OrderlessPatternSequence`, `PatternSequence`, `Repeated`, `RepeatedNull`, `Shortest`}, and `False` otherwise.

`` Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ[expr, var] `` yields `True` if expr is a polynomial in var, and yields `False` otherwise.
Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ[expr, {var1, var2,...}] yields` True`if expr is a polynomial in all var_i, and yields`False` otherwise. ([more info](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102841/how-does-internalpolynomialfunctionq-work))

`` Internal`RadicalMemberQ[rad, {poly1, poly2, ...}] `` tests whether `rad` belongs to the radical of the polynomial ideal generated by `poly1`, `poly2`,... ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118262/2048))

`` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[expr] `` gives `True` if `expr` has a minus sign *vague... needs to be clarified*  ([application](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126759/2048))

---

## Other Internal`'s

`` Internal`BinomialPrimePowerDecomposition[n,m] `` gives a `` Internal`FactoredNumber `` object containing the list of prime factors of the binomial coefficient (n,m) together with their exponents.

`` Internal`ConditionalValueBody[inputHead,{test1, test2, ...},{{msgName1,arg1A,arg1B,...},{msgName2,arg2A,arg2B,...},...},body] `` evaluates each of the `test_i` in turn and if any yields `False`, immediately generates the corresponding `inputHead::msgName_i` Message with arguments `arg_iA`, `arg_iB`,... and returns `Fail`; otherwise evaluates `body`.

`` Internal`CompareNumeric[prec, a, b] `` returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` according to whether `a` is less, equal, or greater than `b` when compared at the precision of `a` or `b` (whichever is less) minus `prec` decimal digits of "tolerance". It is the fundamental operation underlying `Less`, `Equal`, `Greater`, `LessEqual` etc. for finite-precision numeric types. ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118797/machine-precision-and-arbitrary-precision/118808#comment342896_118808)) ([more info](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140528/how-does-internalcomparenumeric-work))

`` Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[n, "Metric" -> {list of +/-1},  "Basis" -> ("Dirac"/"Chiral")] `` returns the nth [Dirac Gamma matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices).

`` Internal`ListMin[matrix] `` returns `matrix` with rows that has all elements greater or equal to elements of another removed.  ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152910/the-polynomial-function-changed-to-a-set-consisting-of-terms-of-polynomial-funct/152932?noredirect=1#comment408553_152932))

`` Internal`Metric `` is an option to `` Internal`DiracGammaMatrix ``.

`` Internal`JoinOrFail[list1, list2] `` returns the list formed by appending list2 to the end of list1.

`` Internal`PerfectPower[integer] `` gives the list of integers {n,p} such that integer is n^p.

`` Internal`RiccatiSolve[{a, b}, {q, r}] `` solves the continuous time algebraic Riccati equation.  (this is a [documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiccatiSolve.html) `System` function)

`` Internal`DiscreteRiccatiSolve[{a, b}, {q, r}] `` solves the discrete time algebraic Riccati equation.  (this is a [documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteRiccatiSolve.html) `System` function)

`` Internal`MakePolynomial[expr] `` returns the form of *expr* in terms of new variables, such that *expr* is polynomial in the new variables.  ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78233/any-way-of-solving-this-system-of-nonlinear-equations-with-non-integer-powers#comment212092_78233))

`` Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[expr, toll] `` replaces the floating point numbers in `expr` with their equivalence class representatives according to the specified tolerance `toll` ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151115/2048)).

---

## System`Utilities`

`` System`Utilities`ExprLookupAdd[expr] `` stores `expr` to memory and returns an integer (not machine sized) key for retrieval.

`` System`Utilities`ExprLookup[integer] `` returns the corresponding `expr`
if `int` is a valid integer key, and returns `$Failed` otherwise.

`` System`Utilities`SymbolList[expr] `` returns a list of atomic `Symbol`s (including heads) in `expr`.
`` System`Utilities`SymbolList[expr, f] `` applies `f` to each `Symbol` before evaluating them.
`` System`Utilities`SymbolList[expr, f, {"Context1`", ...}] `` omits symbols belonging to contexts `` Context1` `` , etc.

`` System`Utilities`Hash* `` (12 functions) ([more info](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105664/2048))

---

## Some more stuff

`` Reduce`FreeVariables[expr] `` <s>returns a `List` of `Symbol`s in `expr` ([more info](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135539/2048))</s>.  **Unclear. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212270/what-does-reducefreevariables-really-do-and-can-we-rely-on-it) for discussion.**

`` GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets[list, n] `` evaluates to a list of multisets of size `n` with elements drawn from `list` (so, repetitions are allowed, but order is irrelevant). For example, `GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets[{a, b, c}, 2]` yields `{{a,a},{a,b},{a,c},{b,b},{b,c},{c,c}}` (as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268721/63584)).

`` GroupTheory`Tools`MultiSubsets[list, {n, m}] ``, if n + m = Length(list), gives the set of subsets of exactly n elements appended to the set of subsets of exactly m elements in reverse order. (equivalent to `MultiSubsets[list_, {n, m}] /; Length[list] == n + m :=  Join @@@ Transpose[{Subsets[list, {m}, Binomial[n + m, n]],  Reverse[Subsets[list, {n}, -Binomial[n + m, n]]]}]` and not much faster) **To figure out: What if n + m ≠ Length(list)?**

`` GroupTheory`Tools`PartitionRagged[list, {n1, n2, ...}] `` seems to be equivalent to `` Internal`PartitionRagged[list, {n1, n2, ...}] ``, but works even if `n1 + n2 ...` ≠ `Length[list]`.

`` GroupTheory`Tools`IntegerPartitionCounts[n] `` returns a list of lists corresponding to number (counts) of integers appearing in each partition.  (the correspondence with `IntegerPartitions[n]` appears to be reversed).

`` GroupTheory`Tools`ConsecutiveReplace[expr,{patt1->list1, patt2->list2,...}] `` replaces elements of `expr` (`Head` usually `List`) that match `patt1`, `patt2`, ... with elements of `list1`, `list2` ... in the order they appear in `expr`.  If any of the `list1`, `list2`, ... are exhausted, it wraps around.

`` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[expr, {x, x0, x1}] `` performs the definite integration by attempting various substitutions of the form `u == g[x]` where `g[x]` is an expression in the integrand. ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128393/2048)) ([application](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6695/2048)) ([application](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175614/2048))

Comment: Note that `RationalFunctionQ` works on trig expressions such as ``Internal`RationalFunctionQ[Tan[x] + 1/(Csc[x] - 1), {Sin[x], Cos[x]}]``. It does not work on all expressions equivalent to a rational function though; for instance, ``Internal`RationalFunctionQ[Sin[2 ArcTan[x]], x]``.

Comment: Is ``GroupTheory`Tools`ConsecutiveReplace`` of no use? (Does "Consecutive" mean "Repeated"?)

Answer (score 45):

#### `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``

This one has a usage statement!

[image]

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[14], {3, 5, 2, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14}}
> ```

Note that `Length[list]` must equal `n1 + ... + nk`.

```
(* changed the last 4 to 3 *)
Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[14], {3, 5, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[14], {3, 5, 2, 3}]
> ```

#### `` Internal`S1, Internal`S2, Internal`P2 ``

> Is it possible to have a documentation of these ***frequently-used*** functions with the help of the users in this community?

These guy's aren't frequently used (and probably aren't used at all), but they're really mysterious looking.

After reading [this](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/meissel.lehmer.pdf) paper, I realized they're submethods used in computing `PrimePi`.

```
With[{x = 10^9},
  {
    PrimePi[x],
    Internal`S1[x] + Internal`S2[x] + Internal`P2[x] + PrimePi[x^(1/3)] - 1
  }
]
```

> ```
> {50847534, 50847534}
> ```

#### `` Internal`Square ``

```
??Internal`Square
(* Attributes[Internal`Square] = {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected} *)
```

Test it with a list:

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 10^8];

r1 = list*list; // RepeatedTiming
(* 0.118 seconds *)
r2 = list^2; // RepeatedTiming
(* 0.191 seconds *)
r3 = Internal`Square[list]; // RepeatedTiming
(* 0.121 seconds *)
```

The advantage of this function seems to come when computing higher powers on a list:

```
lis = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7];

lis*lis*lis*lis; // RepeatedTiming
(* 0.55 seconds *)
lis^4; // RepeatedTiming
(* 0.21 seconds *)
Internal`Square @ Internal`Square @ lis; // RepeatedTiming
(* 0.15 seconds *)
```

Comment: +1, It is very convenient to utilize ``Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[# (# + 1)/2], Range@#] &[5]``  to achieve the following lists `(*{{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}}*)`

Comment: @ShutaoTang regarding `PartitionRagged` I like [my own implementation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7512/121) better as it does things `PartitionRagged` does not.  I hope you will give it a look.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I have known your neat implementation last year.

Comment: @ShutaoTang Okay. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really hard for me to decide whose answer is the best one. Since @blochwave is the first answer, I give this bounty to his answer. I'm sorry, I can only vote up for yours:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Will you happy this?<code> In[76]:= SymbolicTensors`SymbolicTensorsDump`MultiRange[Range[5]] Out[76]= {{1},{2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15}}</code>

Comment: In[76]:= SymbolicTensors`SymbolicTensorsDump`MultiRange[Range[5]] Out[76]= {{1},{2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15}}

Comment: Isn't this just the documented `TakeList`?

Comment: Yes, looks like they exposed ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` through `TakeList` back in 2017.

Answer (score 44):

#### `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``

- [What does Internal`InheritedBlock do?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25769/what-does-internalinheritedblock-do)
- [Daniel's MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00710.html)
- [Strange behaviour of Internal`InheritedBlock](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34698/strange-behaviour-of-internalinheritedblock)
- [How safe is the use of Block and Internal`InheritedBlock](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25673/how-safe-is-the-use-of-block-and-internalinheritedblock)

#### `` Internal`Localizedblock ``

- [What is the purpose of Internal`LocalizedBlock?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71881/what-is-the-purpose-of-internallocalizedblock)

#### `` Internal`Bag ``

- [Internal`Bag inside Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile)
- [Daniel Lichtblau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691491/implementing-a-quadtree-in-mathematica/6795762#6795762)
- [On the use of of Internal`Bag, and any official documenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662704/on-the-use-of-of-internalbag-and-any-official-documenation?lq=1)

> - `Bag` creates an expression bag, optionally with preset elements.
> - `BagPart` obtains parts of an expression bag, similar to `Part` for ordinary expressions. It can also be used on the lhs, e.g. to reset a value.
>   `StuffBag` appends elements to the end of a bag.
> - We also have a `BagLength`, which is useful for iterating over a bag.

#### `` Internal`RationalNoReduce ``

- [Chip Hurst's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69894/how-to-prevent-simplification/69901#69901)

#### `` Internal`Periodicals ``

- [Internal "Periodical" functions in version 7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2806/internal-periodical-functions-in-version-7/2807#2807)

#### `` Internal`StringToDouble ``

- [Oleksandr R.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-do-you-convert-a-string-containing-a-number-in-c-scientific-notation-to-a-ma/1744#1744)

#### `` Internal`Bag ``, `` Internal`StuffBag ``, `` Internal`BagPart ``

- [position of sequence of elements in list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/position-of-sequence-of-elements-in-list/8926#8926)

#### `` Compile`GetElement ``

- [Has this implementation of FDM touched the speed limit of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61509/has-this-implementation-of-fdm-touched-the-speed-limit-of-mathematica/61597#61597)
- [Speed up the auxiliary function magicSquare when $n$ is doubly-even](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82702/speed-up-the-auxiliary-function-magicsquare-when-n-is-doubly-even/82705#82705)

#### `` Internal`FromPiecewise ``

- [How to display the support $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ of a piecewise function $z = f(x,y)$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27252/how-to-display-the-support-suppf-of-a-piecewise-function-z-fx-y/27254#27254)

#### `` Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros ``

- [Removing trailing zeros from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44304/125)

Comment: For ``Internal`Bag``, you should credit Daniel Lichtblau for that explanation, not me. As I noted in my post, that was just a quote from DL's answer which you linked to in the line above. Unrelated note: Using `@username` to ping people in an answer won't actually ping them. @-mentions don't work in answers.

Comment: @TheToad, OK, I got it.

Answer (score 31):

### `` Compile`InnerDo ``

This is the one that initially struck me as interesting since I use compiled functions quite a lot. From the documentation of [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html):

> Unless an explicit `Return` is used, the value returned by `Do` is
>   `Null`.

But that doesn't seem to be the case for `` Compile`InnerDo ``!

```
f1 = Compile[{{x}},
      Module[{a}, a = x; Compile`InnerDo[a++, {i, 10^8}]]
     ]

f2 = Compile[{{x}},
      Module[{a}, a = x; Do[a++, {i, 10^8}]]
     ]

f1[0] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 1.63 seconds, 99999999 *)

f2[0] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 1.63 seconds, Null *)
```

Essentially it adds an extra line into the result of `CompilePrint`:

[image]

---

### `` Compile`Mod1 ``

Seems to be just that, and is listable. In fact, if you write a compilable function that contains `Mod[x, 1]` then it gets compiled down to `` Compile`Mod1 ``.

```
f1 = Compile[{{x}}, Compile`Mod1[x]];
f2 = Compile[{{x}}, Mod[x, 1]];

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint@f1 == CompilePrint@f2
(* True *)
```

---

### `` Compile`DLLFunctionLoad `` / `` Compile`DLLLoad ``

These seem to perform the same functions as [`LibraryFunctionLoad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html):

```
fun1 = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo", "demo_I_I", {Integer}, Integer]
fun2 = Compile`DLLFunctionLoad["demo", "demo_I_I", {Integer}, Integer]
fun1[10] == fun2[10]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 30):

#### Properties for `SparseArray` and `InterpolatingFunction` objects

[`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) objects can accept a range of Properties (or Methods) that allow the efficient extraction of certain information, most commonly `"AdjacencyLists"` or `"NonzeroPositions"` as a frequently faster alternative to [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html).  I started this answer to detail them but as it grew I came to believe that it needs a Q&A of its own, so I posted one:

- [What are SparseArray Properties? How and when should they be used?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83721/121)

Likewise [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) also supports a number of Methods which I have detailed here:

- [How to splice together several instances of InterpolatingFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction/19043#19043)

### Undocumented parameters

For `Normal`: [Is there a way to control which special forms Normal converts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84783/121)

For `Return` and `Break`: [Is there a Break[] equivalent for short-circuiting in Table?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18519/121)

For `Fold` and `FoldList` the two-parameter syntax existed but was undocumented in versions 9.0 through 10.0.1: [Shorter syntax for Fold and FoldList?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121)

Answer (score 26):

No so much a function as an option...

Problem: You embedd a CDF on a web page but the content is rendered as grey boxes.

Cause: This is a security issue, the same as when you open a notebook with dynamic content from an untrusted path on your computer.

Solution: On your desktop you are asked if you want to enable dynamic content. You press the button and everything in your notebook works. By using the "option" {fullscreen:'true'} an embedded CDF will open in "full screen mode" meaning that the enabled content warning will appear and therefore provide your viewers with the button to enable dynamic content.

Usage:

```
<script src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v2.1/cdfplugin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cdf = new cdf_plugin();
cdf.embed("http://path.to/myCDF.cdf", 500, 600,{fullscreen:'true'});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Mike, I found this very useful. Could you write an answer to my question found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5604/877)? I tried what you mentioned here and it seems it could work, but now I face another problem, my CDF now says Initialization timed out after I click on the button to enable the dynamic content.

Answer (score 25):

## `` System`Private`*Entry* `` functions

Since version 10.0 `` System`Private`SetNoEntry `` and `` System`Private`EntryQ `` functions are available.

#### `` System`Private`SetNoEntry ``

Changes internal representation of given expression so that it is considered atomic, it returns "atomized" version of expression. This change affects all references to given expression, but not new expressions even if they are the same.

```
ClearAll[f, x, y, tmp];
tmp = tmp2 = f[x, y];
System`Private`SetNoEntry@tmp (* f[x, y] *)
```

Ordinary `f[x, y]` is not atomic, but all references to `f[x, y]` that was passed to `SetNoEntry` are considered atomic:

```
f[x, y] // AtomQ (* False *)
tmp // AtomQ (* True *)
tmp2 // AtomQ (* True *)
```

Those expressions are still considered same:

```
tmp === f[x, y] (* True *)
```

Head of expression (part 0) is accessible but not other parts:

```
tmp // Head
(* f *)
tmp[[0]]
(* f *)
tmp[[2]]
(* Part::partd: Part specification f[x,y][[2]] is longer than depth of object. *)
(* f[x, y][[2]] *)
```

Part accessing/modifying functions treat it as other atomic objects, so they either complain:

```
Append[tmp, z]
(* Append::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Append[f[x,y],z]. *)
(* Append[f[x, y], z] *)
```

or ignore our expression:

```
ReplacePart[tmp, 1 -> z]
(* f[x, y] *)
```

Pattern matching works as before and can still "go inside" this expression:

```
Replace[tmp, head_[arg1_, arg2_] :> {head, arg1, arg2}]
(* {f, x, y} *)
```

I've learned about this function from [Leonid's answer to "Make my data-structure atomic" post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61625/14303).

#### `` System`Private`NoEntryQ ``

Tests whether given expression was set as "no entry" expression:

```
tmp = f[x, y];
tmp // System`Private`NoEntryQ (* False *)
System`Private`SetNoEntry@tmp;
tmp // System`Private`NoEntryQ (* True *)
```

Some built-in atomic data structures use this mechanism, e.g. `SparseArray`s evaluate to "no entry" atomic form:

```
SparseArray@{0, 1} // Unevaluated // System`Private`NoEntryQ (* False *)
SparseArray@{0, 1} // System`Private`NoEntryQ (* True *)
```

---

Since version 10.4 there are five additional "Entry-related" functions.

#### `` System`Private`EntryQ ``

Is the opposite of `NoEntryQ`:

```
tmp = f[x, y];
tmp // System`Private`EntryQ (* True *)
System`Private`SetNoEntry@tmp;
tmp // System`Private`EntryQ (* False *)
```

#### `` System`Private`HoldSetNoEntry ``

#### `` System`Private`HoldNoEntryQ ``

#### `` System`Private`HoldEntryQ ``

Are variants of `SetNoEntry`, `NoEntryQ` and `EntryQ` with `HoldAllComplete`
attribute.

#### `` System`Private`ConstructNoEntry ``

Creates new "no-entry" expression using first argument as head, and rest of arguments as arguments of created expression:

```
System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[f, x, y] (* f[x, y] *)
% // System`Private`NoEntryQ (* True *)
```

Comment: Interesting. Sadly there doesn't seem to be a `SetEntry` that _un-atomize_ an expression…

Answer (score 23):

Not sure if a new question should be started, anyway, here's some undocumented syntax (sorted alphabetically):

## `Collect`

`Collect` accepts a 4th argument:

[Undocumented fourth parameter of Collect; how long has it been there?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88781/1871)

## `Compile`

Indexed variable can be used as independent variable of `Compile`d function:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
cf = Compile[a[1], Sin@a[1]];
cf // CompilePrint
(* cf is fully compiled *)
```

## `D`

`D[expr]` evaluates to `expr`.

## `Derivative`

`Derivative[][u]` evaluates to `u`.

## `ErrorListPlot`

### 1

`ErrorBar` isn't necessary if there are only symmetric y error bars:

[What's the simplest way to plot an ErrorListPlot with only y error bars?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23192/1871)

### 2

`PlusMinus`(`±`) can be used in `ErrorListPlot`:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77553/1871

## `Exit`/`Quit`/`Return`

`Exit` and `Quit` can work without brackets, `Return` can work without brackets when it's inside a dialog:

[Lists for built-in functions that can work without brackets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67039/1871)

## `FindRoot`

it owns a simple syntax for function relationship that returns number or list of number:

[Mapping multiple functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25745/4999)

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163268/1871

```
FindRoot[x \[Function] Sin[x] + Exp[x], {0}]
(* {-0.588533} *)
FindRoot[{x, y} \[Function] {Exp[x - 2] - y, y^2 - x}, {{1}, {1}}]
(* {0.019026, 0.137935} *)
```

## `ListPlot`/`ListLinePlot`

They can handle `InterpolatingFunction` directly since *v9*:

[Easy way to plot ODE solutions from NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134222/1871)

## `NDSolve`/`NDSolveValue`/`ParametricNDSolve`…

### 1

The 1st argument can be a nested list, no `Flatten` or `Join` is needed:

```
eq = y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0;
bc = {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0};

NDSolve[{eq, bc}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
```

### 2

The 2nd argument can almost be anything:

```
NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y@x Cos[x + y@x], y@0 == 1}, y[x] + y'[x] + Sin[x], {x, 0, 30}]
```

### 3

`"Coordinates"` sub-option of `TensorProductGrid` can be set in the range:

```
grid = {0, 1, 1.1, 3.2, 2.1, 4.6, 5};

seq = Sequence[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t], 
    u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}];

NDSolve[seq, Flatten@{x, grid}] == 
 NDSolve[seq, {x, 0, 5}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "Coordinates" -> grid}}]
(* True *)
```

## `NSolve`

The 1st argument doesn't need to be equation(s):

```
polys = {x^2 + y^2 - 1, 2 x + 3 y - 4};
NSolve[polys, {x, y}]
```

## `Part`

`a[[]]`, or equivalently `Part[a]`, evaluates to `a`.

## `PlotRange`

`PlotRange` can be a function, which returns the plot range of `Graphics`/`Graphics3D`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]
% // Head
(* Graphics *)
%% // PlotRange
(* {{0., 18.8496}, {-0.999999, 0.999999}} *)
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] // PlotRange
% // Head
(* Graphics3D *)
%% // PlotRange
(* {{-2., 2.}, {-2., 2.}, {0., 8.}} *)
```

## `RandomReal`/`RandomInteger`

First argument of them can be a distribution. See:

[RandomReal in combination with NormalDistribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/195058/1871)

## `Reduce`/`Solve`

The 3rd argument can be a list of variables to be eliminated instead of a domain.

For example, `Solve[{x == y + 1, y == 2}, {x}, {y}]` evaluates to `{{x -> 3}}`, whereas `Solve[{x == y + 1, y == 2}, {x}]` evaluates to `{}`.

This syntax is almost hidden since *v8*. (Mentioned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83904/1871).)

## `ReplacePart`

Undocumented since *v6*:

```
ReplacePart[{a, b, c, d, e}, xxx, 3]
(* {a, b, xxx, d, e} *)
ReplacePart[{a, b, c, d, e}, xx, {{2}, {5}}]
(* {a, xx, c, d, xx} *)
```

You need the syntax if you want to compile them because `Rule` isn't compilable:

[error when defining a compiled function with ReplacePart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17339/1871)

## `SumConvergence`

The option value of `Method` can be a user-defined function:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163329/1871

## `Table`

`Table[a]` evaluates to `a`.

Comment: Pure functions as arguments to `FindRoot` are shown in this earlier Q&A: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25745/4999

Comment: ```Unprotect[PlotRange];
ClearAttributes[PlotRange, ReadProtected];
??PlotRange``` then we can see the definition of `PlotRange`

Comment: @xzczd With regard to `Function[Null, ...]`, the three argument form is actually documented. It's specifically the use of `Null` in the two argument form that is undocumented. To me, saying that `Null` is a valid first argument at all strongly suggests that `Null` in the two argument form is valid, so I think it's kind of a stretch to say that this form is truly undocumented.

Comment: @lericr I've edited the statement a bit. Feel free to directly edit it, it's a community wiki :) .

Comment: @domen …May I ask why you've rollbacked to Revision 15?

Comment: @xzczd, because it is not an undocumented function, it is mentioned under the last bullet point for `Function` (I couldn't append comment to the rollback).

Comment: @Domen Oh I should have checked the latest document. (Not sure when that line is added, at least it's not in version 9… )

Answer (score 22):

#### TetGen

*Mathematica* has a nice library `TetGenLink` to produce irregular 3D meshes. Original *TetGen* has a lot of [features](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/features.html) and not all of them available by `TetGenLink`. One of the features is the setting up the vertex metrics to produce non-uniform grids

[image]

Fortunately, the corresponding function is implemented but not documented

```
TetGenSetPointMetricTensors[tetGenInstance, {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, ...}]
```

The mesh size depends only on the first element of the tensors (`x1, x2, x3, ...`).

#### Fractions

Beveled fractions ${}^a/_b$ available with the undocumented option [`Beveled`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33656/4678) in the `FractionBox`.

#### TextRecognize

[`"SegmentationMode"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31851/4678) option can improve `TextRecognize`.

Comment: I only saw this now: The reason it's not documented is that I never could come up with a use case for this TetGen function. If you could point that out to me then it could be documented.

Comment: @user21 I think now with new V10 functional `TetGenLink` is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 21):

Undocumented option **PlotPoints->{n,{p}}**

with **2(!)** parameters n (number of points or Automatic) and **p (list of critical points)**

example

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{1, x == 1}, {0, True}}];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.1}, PlotPoints -> {Automatic, { 1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

`` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``:

```
f[z_] := Piecewise[{{0, 0 < z < 30}, {1, 30 < z < 60}, {0, 60 < z < 120}, {-1, 120 < z < 150}}]

Simplify`PWToUnitStep@f[z]
```

> -(1 - UnitStep[120 - z]) (1 - UnitStep[-150 + z]) + (1 - 
>       UnitStep[30 - z]) (1 - UnitStep[-60 + z])

Comment: And it has an inverse too! Let ``s = Simplify`PWToUnitStep @ f[z]`` then you can get back to the `Piecewise` with `FullSimplify[s]`.

Comment: @bill, or use `PiecewiseExpand[]`.

Answer (score 12):

`LabeledSlider` is a version of `Slider` first mentioned by @ybeltukov in [Can Manipulate controls have the option Appearance -> "Labeled" by default?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32848/can-manipulate-controls-have-the-option-appearance-labeled-by-default/32875#32875).

If you find yourself expanding the sliders in manipulate in order to see the value, just use this form in order to see the value without having to expand the slider:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 1, 10, LabeledSlider}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 11):

## `` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``

This function ([ref#1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/o52ZvBRwuzw/iS8I7miNrLsJ), [ref#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586910/211232), [ref#3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1603/142)) can be used to ensure that some clean-up code will always be executed, even if an abort or other non-local exit occurs within some protected code.  To illustrate:

```
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  Print["opening a file"]
, Print["doing something with the file"]
; Abort[]
; Print["never gets here"]
, Print["closing the file"]
]

(* During evaluation of In[1]:= opening a file
   During evaluation of In[1]:= doing something with the file
   During evaluation of In[1]:= closing the file
   Out[1]= $Aborted
*)
```

Earlier versions of this function did not handle `Catch`/`Throw` properly, but this has been corrected and the function now seems to the most reliable way to protect against the unwinding of the evaluation stack.

## `CheckAll`

In a similar vein, the `CheckAll` function ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48493/142)) ensures that a function is called whenever a body of code was exited, whether normally or abnormally.  Unlike `` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``, the handler code completely intercepts the exit.  To illustrate:

```
CheckAll["normal exit", myHandlerFunction]
(* myHandlerFunction["normal exit", Hold[]] *)

CheckAll[Throw[3], myHandlerFunction]
(* myHandlerFunction[$Aborted, Hold[Throw[3]]] *)
```

The second example shows how the handler function is informed about the exact nature of the exit.  It is up to that function to decide whether to re-evaluate the expression that triggered the exit, thus continuing to pass control up the stack.

Answer (score 10):

## `` Internal`GetIteratorLength ``

`` Internal`GetIteratorLength[it] `` returns the length (= number of iterations to be performed) of a standard iterator `it` such as is used in `Table`.

```
Internal`GetIteratorLength[{x, 3, 10}]
(*  8  *)

Internal`GetIteratorLength[{x, 3, 10, 0.27}]
(*  26  *)

Internal`GetIteratorLength[{x, {3, 4, 7}}]
(*  3  *)

Internal`GetIteratorLength[{4}]
(*  4  *)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I don't see the connection between the inputs and outputs.

Comment: @ChipHurst The number of iterations to be performed is returned (= length of `Table` if used in `Table[]`). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Aha I finally see it now. Thanks!

Comment: `Length[Table[(* anything except Nothing *), {x, 3, 10}]]` is `8` for example.

Comment: @ChipHurst Right, a fencepost problem. And if you use `Nothing`, `Table` will actually create a list of length `8`, but afterwards `Nothing` causes `List` to contract.  E.g. `Table[Nothing, {x, 3, 10}] // Trace`.

Answer (score 8):

## `` Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex ``

It basically does what it says. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/187693) for one of its applications.

## `` Random`Private`MapThreadMin `` and `` Random`Private`MapThreadMax ``

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3131

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164614

## `` Random`Private`PositionsOf ``

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166540

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164614

Answer (score 8):

### `` ValueTrack`CollectTrackEvent ``

This helps with figuring out what caused a `Dynamic` to update:

```
a = 1;
f[x_] := a x^2
ValueTrack`CollectTrackEvent[True]

Dynamic[{ValueTrack`CollectTrackEvent[], f[2]}]
(* {{Hold[a, HoldComplete[a, 1, 2, OwnValues], {909089}]}, 8} *)

a = 2;

ValueTrack`CollectTrackEvent[False]
```

The functionality is enabled using `` ValueTrack`CollectTrackEvent[True] `` and disabled again using `` ValueTrack`CollectTrackEvent[False] ``. While it is enabled, `` ValueTrack`CollectTrackEvent[] `` will return a list of value changes that were tracked by some `Dynamic` (while disabled, it will return `Null`). Some notes:

- `` ValueTrack`CollectTrackEvent[] `` will return the list of all value changes since the last time it was called. It does not matter which `Dynamic` was updated, you simply get one long list.
- The format seems to be

  ```
  {{sym_, update_, {boxIDs__}}...}
  ```

  where `sym` is the symbol causing the update, `update` is a description of the update (which part was updated, old and new value, type of value). The format seems to be the same as for the [`"ValueChange"` handler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120159/how-to-use-handler-functions). Finally, `boxIDs` is a list of IDs of the `DynamicBox` expressions updated by that value change.

Credit goes to Kyle Martin (WRI) for showing this to me. - Thanks again!

There's also `` ValueTrack`GetTrackingState `` and `` ValueTrack`SetTrackingState ``, but I don't know what they do

Answer (score 6):

It is mentioned in a comment, but unless I missed something only there, and I think it deserves small entry.

```
   ?? Internal`AbsSquare
```

> [image: internal]

With

```
cmplx = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^8, 2}] . {1, I};
ntrnl = Internal`AbsSquare[cmplx]; // RepeatedTiming // First
fnctn = Abs[cmplx]^2; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> [image: out1]
>
> [image: out2]

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[Chop[ntrnl - fnctn]]
```

> [image: true]

Answer (score 4):

### `DispatchQ`

[A Curiosity: What is DispatchQ?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224796/12697)

`DispatchQ` returns True if applied to a Dispatch object, so it is useful for identifying Dispatch objects.

Mathematica autofill shows the function `DispatchQ`. It does not appear in the Mathematica Documentation Center. Except for the question linked above, a search for DispatchQ on the Mathematica Stack Exchange comes up with nothing, and a Google search for "DispatchQ" reveals nothing relating to Mathematica.

### `` Compile`SetIterate ``

[What Does Compile`SetIterate Do?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255724/what-does-compilesetiterate-do)

`` Compile`SetIterate `` sets an iterator.

The list of compilable functions (given by `` Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort ``) shows `` Compile`SetIterate ``. It does not appear in the Mathematica Documentation Center. Moreover, except for the question linked above and for references to merely the list of compilable functions, a search for `` Compile`SetIterate `` on the Mathematica Stack Exchange comes up with nothing and a Google search for `` Compile`SetIterate `` reveals nothing I can see relating to Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

```
?SpecialFunctions`*
```

> [image: img]

Special mention for the harmonic polylogarithm and multiple polylogarithm. They seem to be in accord to the definitions of [hep-ph/9905237](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905237) and [hep-ph/0410259](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0410259) respectively.

```
SpecialFunctions`HarmonicPolyLog[{1, -2, 3, 0}, 0.7]
SpecialFunctions`MultiplePolyLog[{1, -2, 3, 0}, {0.7, 1, 1, 1}]
```

> `-0.25112`

> `-0.25112`

Some caution is needed, though. For example in performing `Series` expansion we have to use `FunctionExpand` or `FullSimplify` in the even cases, but not in the odd.

```
Series[PolyLog[2, 1 - x], {x, 0, 1}] // Normal
Series[SpecialFunctions`HarmonicPolyLog[{2}, 1 - x] // 
   FunctionExpand, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal
Series[SpecialFunctions`HarmonicPolyLog[{2}, 1 - x] // 
   FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= 1] &, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

> `π^2/6 + x (-1 + Log[x])`

but

```
Series[SpecialFunctions`HarmonicPolyLog[{2}, 1 - x], {x, 0, 
   2}] // Normal
Series[SpecialFunctions`HarmonicPolyLog[{2}, 1 - x], {x, 0, 
   2}] // Normal
```

> `π^2/6 + (-2 I π x - I π x^2 - 2/3 I π x^3) Floor[-( Arg[x]/(2 π))] - I x (-I + 2 π + I Log[x]) -  1/4 I x^2 (-I + 4 π + 2 I Log[x])`

Note that `// FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= 1] &` after the expansion leads to a difference of

> `-I π x (2 + x)`

I found this [***here***](https://qiita.com/tueda/items/49289003c307b0a88f9b)

Answer (score 2):

```
ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts[InverseFunction[Cos][z], z]
```

> (Re[z]<-1&&Im[z]==0)||(1<Re[z]&&Im[z]==0)

---

To help with this problem, I made a simple extension. Now it's super easy to discover them.

https://github.com/asukaminato0721/mmacompletion

[image]